# Pandas: Passing two columns to an expanding_apply function

Tags: pandas, lambda

I have the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
id = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
value = [1,3,2,5,4,4,3,2,1,5]
test = pd.DataFrame(zip(id, value), columns = ['id', 'value'])
```

And I want an expanding apply function that identifies whether we reach a new maximum value for a given id. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
   id  value  new_max
0   0      1        1    
1   0      3        1    
2   0      2        0    
3   0      5        1    
4   0      4        0    
5   1      4        1    
6   1      3        0    
7   1      2        0    
8   1      1        0    
9   1      5        1
```

I can't seem to pass two columns to the expanding apply function.

I tried by creating a new column:

```
test['id_value'] = zip(test['id'], test['value'])
```

And passing the tuple on:

```
def new_max(x):
    v, w = list(zip(*x)[0]), list(zip(*x)[1])
    last_id = v[-1]
    last_value = w[-1]
    if any(j >= last_value for j in [w[i] for i, k in enumerate(v[0:-1]) if k == last_id]):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1


test['new_max'] = test['id_value'].apply(lambda x: pd.expanding_apply(x, new_max))
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

---

**ONE SOLUTION THAT CIRCUMVENTS PASSING TWO COLUMNS**
(though it would still be nice to know how to do this by passing two columns)

```
def new_max2(x):
    if any(j >= x[-1] for j in x[0:-1]):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

test.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.expanding_apply(x, new_max2))
```

Comment: If you have a new maximum immediately followed by the same value repeated, e.g. [5,1,2,3,6,6], do you want both 6s to have a 1 or only the first?  (I'm assuming you only want the first, because it's the one that set the new max.)

Comment: @DSM (Only the first, and I wrote that code wrong, so I'll edit) Thanks for the response. I just figured it out, actually. Circumvents the passing along of two columns, though if someone knows how to do that, it might be helpful for anyone else with this question. I'll post my particular solution up there with the question.

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the problem, not the general issue of passing multiple columns: I would use `groupby` and `cummax`, and then see whether we hit a new value.  For example:

```
grouped = df.groupby("id")["value"]
cummax = grouped.cummax()
cummax_is_new_value = cummax != cummax.groupby(df.id).shift()
df["new_max"] = cummax_is_new_value.astype(int)
```

gives me

```
>>> df
    id  value  new_max
0    0      1        1
1    0      3        1
2    0      2        0
3    0      5        1
4    0      4        0
5    1      4        1
6    1      3        0
7    1      2        0
8    1      1        0
9    1      5        1
10   2      1        1
10   2      1        0
10   2      0        0
10   2      1        0
10   3      1        1
```

Originally I was only checking whether the value was the same as the previous value, but that failed on cases like [1, 0, 1], where the second 1 is both equal to the cumulative maximum and not the same as the previous value.  This way we're always working with the grouped cumulative values, and so we really are only picking up the new cumulative values by group.

Comment: Thanks, @DSM, much more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time since I worked with `apply` like a couple releases ago minimum, so my recollection may be bad, or things may have changed. However, as I remember it the grouped data is passed automatically as the first argument.

The temptation when passing your own function to `apply` is to do this:

```
def user_func(df, arg1, arg2):
    return whatever_you_like

DF = pd.DataFrame(your_data)

DF.groupby('col1').appy(user_func(arg1, arg2))
```

but this is not the correct syntax. In fact the correct syntax for the last line is

```
DF.groupby('col1').apply(user_func, arg1, arg2)
```

Whether `expanding_apply` works in the same way I do not know and this may all be totally out of date, but might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is a more generic solution (not vectorised) using list comprehensions:

Let's say you have 2 columns, a and b.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3], b=[4,5,6]))
```

And you want to calculate the running ratio of the sum of and and b

```py
def myFunc(df): 
    return df["a"].sum() / df["b"].sum()
```

Here is a solution that works provided your function takes a dataframe and outputs a single value

```py
df.assign(sum_a_sum_b_ratio = [myFunc(d) for d in df.expanding()])
```

```
    a   b   sum_a_sum_b_ratio
0   1   4   0.250000
1   2   5   0.333333
2   3   6   0.400000
```